# Why is ajax request working cross-domain in the google extension sample without jsonp?

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, flickr

I was going through the tutorial for making a simple chrome extension which gets images from the **flicker api** and loads them into the extension popup.[Making a simple chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

I just cant understand one thing. The **ajax** request made here is a simple get request. Why is it working **cross-domain**. Its not even JSONP.  The script file popup.js is as follows

```
    // Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

/**
 * Global variable containing the query we'd like to pass to Flickr. In this
 * case, kittens!
 *
 * @type {string}
 */
var QUERY = 'kittens';

var kittenGenerator = {
  /**
   * Flickr URL that will give us lots and lots of whatever we're looking for.
   *
   * See http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html for
   * details about the construction of this URL.
   *
   * @type {string}
   * @private
   */
  searchOnFlickr_: 'https://secure.flickr.com/services/rest/?' +
      'method=flickr.photos.search&' +
      'api_key=90485e931f687a9b9c2a66bf58a3861a&' +
      'text=' + encodeURIComponent(QUERY) + '&' +
      'safe_search=1&' +
      'content_type=1&' +
      'sort=interestingness-desc&' +
      'per_page=20',

  /**
   * Sends an XHR GET request to grab photos of lots and lots of kittens. The
   * XHR's 'onload' event is hooks up to the 'showPhotos_' method.
   *
   * @public
   */
  requestKittens: function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", this.searchOnFlickr_, true);
    req.onload = this.showPhotos_.bind(this);
    req.send(null);
  },

  /**
   * Handle the 'onload' event of our kitten XHR request, generated in
   * 'requestKittens', by generating 'img' elements, and stuffing them into
   * the document for display.
   *
   * @param {ProgressEvent} e The XHR ProgressEvent.
   * @private
   */
  showPhotos_: function (e) {
    var kittens = e.target.responseXML.querySelectorAll('photo');
    for (var i = 0; i < kittens.length; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.constructKittenURL_(kittens[i]);
      img.setAttribute('alt', kittens[i].getAttribute('title'));
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
  },

  /**
   * Given a photo, construct a URL using the method outlined at
   * http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urlKittenl
   *
   * @param {DOMElement} A kitten.
   * @return {string} The kitten's URL.
   * @private
   */
  constructKittenURL_: function (photo) {
    return "http://farm" + photo.getAttribute("farm") +
        ".static.flickr.com/" + photo.getAttribute("server") +
        "/" + photo.getAttribute("id") +
        "_" + photo.getAttribute("secret") +
        "_s.jpg";
  }
};

// Run our kitten generation script as soon as the document's DOM is ready.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  kittenGenerator.requestKittens();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Its [**CORS**](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

In the Flicker API, the response header has Access Control Allow Origin header set to *.
 Hence, any ajax request would work.

You need to edit your server configuration file if u need to set this header. By default its not *.